# Retriving data from facebook events

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have to create an webpage where i need to show all the events from the past or upcoming ones from an facebook page. I have to retrive the title, description, image, time and place of every single one and make a box with it.
After that, i have to retrive all the interested people.

I'm a beginner trying to make big things! Thank you very much.

Comment: So what have you done so far? What is your question?

Comment: Well.. i don't really know from where to start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isnt a simple problem - I have just done this so will give you a start.

You need to use Facebooks Graph API to get the data, you will need to read up on the Graph API and how to use it. Documentation can be found [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api). Its worth noting due to a security breach the API isn't offering all of its services to new developers currently but you can get most - read about this [here](https://newsroom.fb.com/news/2018/03/cracking-down-on-platform-abuse/).

You can query the API using any language but I suggest do it with python and use the requests module. Alternatively you could use [this SDK](https://github.com/mobolic/facebook-sdk) which makes things a lot easier, trust me! With the SDK you need to get a user access token which you can get from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/).

**SDK**

With the SDK its possible to do this

```
import facebook
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token="your_token", version="2.12")
event = graph.get_object(id='event_id',
                         fields='attending_count,declined_count')
print(event['attending_count'])
print(event['declined_count'])
```

You can add more fields to the fields list. However you can use any language you choose to request the data, as you can just construct your own URL's.

**Graph API & Requests**

This is how I did it in python using requests to query the API.

```
import requests, json

#Make a requests session to fetch data from URL's
session = requests.Session()
session.mount('https://', requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter(max_retries=10))

#API base URL
baseUrl = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/'

#Fields you want to get
fields = ['id', 'name', 'start_time', 'end_time', 'description', 'place']

#replace CLIENT_ID and CLIENT_SECRET with ones from a facebook app (make one)
tokenPath= 'oauth/access_token?client_id={0}&client_secret={1}&&'\
              'grant_type=client_credentials'.format(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET)
#Get the generated token
token = session.get(baseUrl + tokenPath).json()['access_token']

event = session.get(baseUrl, params={
            "ids": "event_id",
            "fields": ",".join(fields),
            "access_token": token,
        }
    ).json()

print(event["name"])
print(event["place"])
```

You can make a facebook app [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/register) which is where the `CLIENT_ID` & `CLIENT_SECRET` come from.

**Why would you use URL requests and not the SDK?**

Using the SDK the generated user access tokens expire every day, its possible to extend them but only for 60 days. If you want to use the SDK it has a method built in which allows you to extend the token, in order to extend the token you also need to create a facebook app. Its also possible to extend tokens using [this website](https://smashballoon.com/custom-facebook-feed/docs/get-extended-facebook-user-access-token/), though I cant vouch for its security - it could potentially access and exploit your data.

To extend the token with SDK:

```
import facebook
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(user_access_short_lived_token)
extended_token = graph.extend_access_token(app_id, app_secret)
print(extended_token)
```

Using the URL approach, you create a client access token at runtime (read about user access token vs client access token [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12889908/facebook-user-access-token-vs-app-access-token)) and the token is valid so long as your app is active. So if you are going to use this a lot or want to create it and not have to change/extend tokens then use the URL approach.

Hope this gets you started.